# Why Openshift adds cache-control private?

Tags: python, caching, flask, openshift, openshift-origin

My flask python service on Openshift Origin is adding a `Cache-Control: private`.
My cache server does not make cache because this.
How can I remove this from service?

I Have added this configuration but has no effect:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Route
metadata:
  annotations:
    haproxy.router.openshift.io/disable_cookies: 'true'
```

When I performa a `curl` the header still returns:

```
$ curl -I http://api.example.com/
HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 87160
Cache-Control: max-age=300
Vary: Accept
Expires: Fri, 07 Apr 2017 18:09:44 GMT
Set-Cookie: OPENSHIFT_EDGE_example-api_example-api_SERVERID=8326069cf7d473e9305855a9a08aaef4; path=/; HttpOnly; Secure
Cache-control: private
Connection: keep-alive
```

Answer (score 3):

At a guess the haproxy router in OpenShift adds this because by default it uses a cookie to implement sticky sessions, to try and ensure traffic from a user goes back to same application instance.

- https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.4/architecture/core_concepts/routes.html#haproxy-template-router

As a result, the cookie being returned would be specific to the user.

There is a way of changing how haproxy manages this, but not sure of details of what you need to change.

Comment: I neet to remove the `Cache-Control: private` from output to cache the service response

Comment: Yes, sticky sessions are the reason why this header is added. See the answer to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44663089/how-to-disable-sticky-sessions-in-openshift3/45702483

Answer (score 2):

[Graham](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43267327/435004) is correct, this is a sticky session issue.

Remove the `haproxy.router.openshift.io/balance: roundrobin` annotation from the route, and the `Cache-Control: private` goes away.

Answer (score 1):

a haproxy.router.openshift.io/disable_cookies: 'true' annotation does also help