# Duplicate Cache-Control header in Spring Boot application

Tags: spring-boot, openshift, cache-control

We have a Spring Boot application that runs in Openshift where we configure the Cache-Control header like this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.headers().cacheControl().disable().addHeaderWriter((httpServletRequest, httpServletResponse) -> {
            httpServletResponse.setHeader(HttpHeaders.CACHE_CONTROL, "public, max-age=86400");
        });
    }
}
```

In the HTTP responses there are two Cache-Control headers:

```
$ curl --header https://<our-url> --head
HTTP/1.1 200 Connection established

HTTP/1.1 200
...
Cache-Control: public, max-age=86400
...
Cache-control: private
```

We expect the first header, and we have no idea where the second header comes from. (Note the lowercase c in the name of the second header.)

Any ideas where the second header comes from and how we can get rid of it?

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer: The Cache-control header is added by [HAProxy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HAProxy). HAProxy uses this header and a cookie to create sticky sessions (i.e. to make sure that requests from the same client are handled by the same pod).

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44663089/how-to-disable-sticky-sessions-in-openshift3/45702483) for details.

In short, you can disable this behaviour by

```
oc annotate route <myroute> haproxy.router.openshift.io/disable_cookies='true'
```